# CSS background-attachment:fixed hiding image

Tags: html, css

I have two div in my HTML page. I am using background image for second div with `background-attachement:fixed`. But some part of image is hiding behind on first `div`. My First `div` height is `50px` and `50px` of image is hiding behind it. I dont know why this is happening. [fidded](http://jsfiddle.net/eoLsu0ra/4/embedded/result/)

**//HTML**

```
<div style="height:50px; background:#d7d7d7">aa</div>
<div class="image"></div>
```

**//css**

```
.image{ width:970px; background:url('http://www.lavu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/banner_1300x226_10.jpg') left top no-repeat; height:400px; background-attachment:fixed}
```

Comment: not hiding.. second `div`is below first `div` without interception

Comment: your fiddle seems to work fine for me

Comment: @Pete: my second div image is beind first div. if you remove background fixed property then you could see the difference

Comment: To see the difference please play with background attachment property

Comment: @amit the point of fixed is that it is positioned fixed to the viewpoint.  From  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment:  This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, a ‘fixed’ background doesn't move with the element.  What is the purpose of using fixed in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the height of your first div remains the same, you can specify its height in the vertical value of `background-position` to 50px. If the height will vary I believe you'll have to rely on JS.

```
.image {
    background: url("http://www.lavu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/banner_1300x226_10.jpg") no-repeat fixed left 50px transparent
}
```

When you use `fixed` the image is positioned relative to the viewport and ignores the presence of any surrounding elements, similar to how an element behaves when you use `position: fixed;`

Comment: Is there any other way to fix it

Comment: @amit: To my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following background-attachment:fixed from the class ".image"

Give it like this:

```
.image {
width: 970px;
background: url('http://www.lavu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/banner_1300x226_10.jpg') left top no-repeat;
height: 400px;
}
```